# Protractor: test fails with browser.actions() after a previous click

Tags: angularjs, automated-tests, protractor

I have a problem regarding automated tests in protractor.

I have two iterations:

```
it('first iteration', function(){
 element.click()
});

it('second iteration', function(){
 // move mouse to specific position and click on it
 browser.actions().mouseMove({x: 5, y: 5}).click().perform();
});
```

If i run each one separately, it works perfectly, but if i run the 2 iterations, the second action never happens.

Am i missing something, or is this an issue?

**EDIT 1:**

I have a beforeEach where i 'clean' each iteration and where i initialize my page object each time.

```
beforeEach(function () {
    browser.clearMockModules();
    browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
    pageModule = new PagePO();
});
```

I am testing a slider that changes values in a different element, so i need to move the mouse to a specific point in the slider and click there.

Cheers

Comment: Could you provide your protractor file? Do you use for instance a `beforeEach` that modify the page? And maybe some context on the goal of your test?

Comment: Adlen Afane i have update my question with my beforeEach. My protractor file is pretty straightforward. Something like:
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['spec.js'],
  capabilities = {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        args: ['test-type']
    }
  }
}

Comment: 'the second action never happens' what happens? nothing? an error message?

Comment: No error. I mean, the slider don't change it's value, so the next expectations fails. But if i run only the second 'it', the slider changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, we found the problem.

It seems that the action **mouseMove**, moves the mouse since the last position of the mouse. I was assuming that the starting position was always *0, 0* but that is not the case.

In this case i wanted to click in the position *0, 0* of an element so it was solved this way:

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(element).click();
```

Cheers

Comment: I thing it should be: `browser.actions().mouseMove(element).click().perform()`